# Importing a Java Package in root directory

Tags: java, import, package, sphinx

I am in a sub domain subdomain.site.com and there is a java package higher up in the root directory at `/usr/share/sphinx/api/java`.

The typical thing to do to import this package would be to write

```
import sphinx.api.java;
```

However when I just do that, I get a package does not exist error.

What's the solution to this? Some sort of path definition?

(Im on Linux CentOS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a package, that is a directory structure. I seriously doubt that is a actual package definition. If a class is there, it probably is in the `default` package which in the newer JDKs can't be imported.

Answer (score -1):

you're missing the semi-colon at the end of the line:

```
import sphinx.api.java;
```